# Is it ok to use click events for small operations in WPF (MVVM)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application implemented using MVVM. But for some small operations, such as scroll, confirmation box button click, left click operation, right click operation, etc, I am using click events directly in views.

I know MVVM does not recommend this, but is it ok to have such click events or its a bad coding practice while using MVVM? What are pros and cons of using this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the MVVM pattern gives you:

- Seperation of concerns (which is true for all UI patterns)
- Unit testing of view logic, by executing the view-model without the view.
- Developer-Designer workflow, allowing designers using Blend to work on the same code.

If handling UI events in code behind doesn't prohibit the above, then there is no problem. Personally I use commands if I can, but am not concerned if there is a little code-behind required.

Events *can* be used, but the problem with allowing codebehind events is that it's a slippery slope. you add one thing, then you add another, and all of a sudden you create actual logic in the codebehind class. (It's even more prominent if you are working with other less experienced programmers in your team).

That's why some programmers prefer, to almost no exceptions, to not write codebehind AT ALL. 
Every code that fits the codebehind without being really application-logic code can also be written within a Behavior, which makes the architecture much more strict and simple to define.

Answer (score 1):

If your button does something that is specific to your UI then yes you should use event handlers over commands.

e.g. If you have a button that scrolls a ScrollViewer control to the bottom then it would be bad practice to use an MVVM style command as your ViewModel would need knowledge and direct control of the view. For these situations the view should be self contained.

If your button needs to do something with data then you should use a command and perform the operation in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with @Noam M. Just to extend his answer:

Whether it's violation of MVVM or not depends on what you acually do in eventhandlers. If it's logic that is covered by the view responsibility, it's perfectly ok.

- For example, PasswordBox password property cannot be databound, because it is not DependencyProperty and using PasswordChanged eventhander to set viewmodel property is perfectly ok. However, if you wrote password validation against server, that would be violation of mvvm.
- I often use Loaded/Unloaded events to call Activate/Deactivate methods on my VM. When I use it too often I create behavior implemented as attached property, that does it for me, so I don't have to repeat the same code in code behind multiple times
- I often use DataGrid's events in codebehind, like sorting etc.
- I use TextBox.GotFocus event to select all text. Again, I create behavior when I need to reuse it.
- I use codebehind to trigger, or create animations if it would be too complicated in xaml. In that case I just leave comment in xaml for other developers.
- In MVVM application not all assets must be strictly written using MVVM. For example I have just written my ModalDialogWindow, where I inject content and buttons. I don't have viewmodel for this control and I do everything from codebehind. However, my application has solid MVVM architecture and I show modal dialogs from my page viewmodels using IDialogService. The ModalDialogWindow does not break testability, blendability, or readbility of my application, because in test I mock the IDialogService anyway and I don't need to test ModalDialogWindow UI itself.